# running hadoop-free spark build on windows 10

Tags: windows, apache-spark, hadoop

currently i installed Hadoop ver 3.2.3 on windows 10 and there is no problem running it. i also downloaded spark-3.3.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz and set Enviornment variable SPARK_HOME appropriately.
i also check hadoop classpath and it returned:

```
C:\hadoop-3.2.3\etc\hadoop;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\common;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\common\lib\*;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\common\*;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\hdfs;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\hdfs\*;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\yarn;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\yarn\*;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*;C:\hadoop-3.2.3\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*
```

seem's fine.
and i added

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
```

in the spark-env.sh
but still when i type spark-shell or pyspark command in command line i get the famous error

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
```

...
the path seem's to be right.
any idea what should i do now?
thanks for your attention!

Comment: You can try installing Spark Standalone Instance using this alternate method - https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-windows-10

Comment: that was one brief&shine guide for installing spark! thanks... but still need to solve the path problem and let spark query reach the data stored on HDFS...

Comment: spark-env.sh is only used on Unix, not in Windows unless you are using WSL2